# Handling Heroku/ClearDB auto Increment primary key strategy

Tags: php, mysql, sql, heroku, cleardb

With Heroku running ClearDB as the MySQL layer, primary keys are auto-incremented in multiples of 10. So, for example, the first insert could be 4 then 14, 24, 34 etc. I fully accept their reasoning for this, so that's not the issue.

My question is, how do you handle this within your code. For example, let's say I have a `status` table which consists of 4 rows,

```
     id | name
     1  | Active
     2  | Retired
     3  | Banned
     4  | Awaiting Mod
```

And then within my application I use:

```
   if($status['id'] == 1){
     //do something
   }else{
     // do something else
   }
```

Clearly this will break, due to the way the PK's are incremented. What is the best practice for handling situations like these? I cannot, for example, check for a 14 as there's nothing to say the numbering strategy won't change to 12, 22, 32, etc.

Should I be checking by name eg, `if($status['name'] == 'Active')` or do I add a new column to the table with the `int`s I require? I know querying by `int` in SQL is far quicker than by `string`.

So, what is the *normal* way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two strategies to handle that

### No auto-increment

Don't use the auto-increment. Simply add the id values yourself, when inserting data. For a table like 'status', that probably contains only static data, you don't dynamically change, that might be good option.

### String constants

Check for the string values. And define those strings as class constants.

```
class YourClass {
  const ACTIVE = 'Active';
  const RETIRED = 'Retired';
  ...
}
```

And then write your checks as

```
if($status['name'] == self::ACTIVE){
  //do something
}
```

I'd recommend to use the second approach, mostly because it makes your code more semantic. Its much easier to see what `$status['name'] == self::RETIRED` means than `$status['id'] == 2`

And if you add an index on the `name` column on that table there won't be (almost) any difference in performance when you query by name instead of by primary key.

Comment: Great answer. I think I'll actually end up  implementing both strategys. A non incrementing table, with a class which maps to a semantic code reference. Thank you.